# Syncing up filters across many kendo grids

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I wand to have 3 grids with the same datasource. All grids will have some common columns and some specific for a grid. Example:

Grid1:

ProducId, ProductName, ProductQuantity

Grid2:

ProducId, ProductName, OrdersCount

Now I want to have synced up all the filter fields. For example, if I type in "Car x" in Grid1, ProductName filter, I want it to appear in Grid2 in the same filter. And both grids should be filtered. If I clear this filter in any of the grids, it should be cleared in all grids.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to sync all the grids that share the same datasource. Just filter their datasource.

```
$("#grid1").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter({ field: "ProductName", operator: "contains", value: "oil" });
```

See demo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oruj8rja/)